# how to convert yii framework project into php

Tags: php, yii

can any one help me. actually I create yii framework project.how i convert into php in easiest way.Actually i know  little  concept of mvc using in php but the problem is render,redirect,lot of pages create through MVC . how i control admin panel .
actually i create differt admin panel for media person and agent.i dont understand if i extends from ccontroller in yii but how i use in php also..

lot of confusion for me about this project. can any one help me as easiest way as possible.if you describe that will better for me.
Please help. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can you be more specific? Yii **is** PHP...

Comment: actually client don't need any framework..only use php .and I know framework also build in php.

Comment: can you give this answer with description.

Answer (score 0):

Let me be clear.

PHP is a server-side scripting language.

The Yii Framework is an instrument, which supports the development process and relieve the "Programmer" with common activities. The Framework itself is build on PHP, because of this, there is no "converting".

My advice to you: Check the requirements given by your client carefully. After that, you have probablary two Options.

1. coding all Functionality by yourself in PHP
2. checkout a cool Framework and spent some time learning

Comment: can you give me some idea how i  use yii project in core php...actulluy client not need any framework..